# How can i have a python flask-socketio script acting as a local server and as a remote client at the same time?

Tags: node.js, server, client, flask-socketio

**My working setup at the moment:**
I have an app which consists of a python flask-socketio server and a react interface. The python server collects some data from a specific connected hardware and sends it through sockets to the react interface.

**What i want to add:**
Besides the actual functionalities, I also want to add a communication through sockets between the local python server and a remote node server. It is possible for local python server to act as a local server and a remote client?

**What i have tried:**
I tried to add code for a socketio client on the main script of python server.
here:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import socketio

socketio_server = SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent', engineio_logger=False)

####PART OF THE CODE THAT I TRIED TO ADD THE COMMUNICATION AS A CLIENT###

##Connecting to server as a client
sio = socketio.Client()  # !!! at this point i receive a new connection on remote server, however the code freezes on this line and the script hang on until the end of the connection
sio = socketio.Connect(host, port)
#i want to send data to a specific namespace
sio.emit('remote-client', {'foo':'bar'}) 

########################################################################

# Serve React App
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path != "" and os.path.exists("static" + path):
        return send_from_directory('static', path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory('static', 'index.html')


#---------------------Web Sockets-----------------------------#

@socketio_server.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print 'Client Connected'

@socketio_server.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print 'Client disconnected'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Server..."
    socketio_server.run(app, debug=False)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

So, is this the right approach to achieve what I want? If it is, how can the python script act as a socketio server and client at the same time?

Regards, 
Ricardo

EDIT: I Just realized that I am able to use ordinary sockets (import socket) along with socketio server. But if you have a better approach I will consider!

Comment: You should be able to use the `socketio.Client` class within the context of a server process, I do not see a problem there. Where is your `sio.connect()` call though? You don't have it in the code above.

Comment: I am sorry, i deleted by mistake. sio = socketio.connect(host, port) is on the line after sio = socketio.Client(). And it is precisely there where the code freeze. I am going to edit it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling `sio.wait()` after connect? It would be expected that a call to `wait()` blocks, but not for connect. You may want to enable logging to see if that provides additional clues. Use `socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)` to create a client that also logs.